# Finding duplicated column value pairs in sql table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, multiple-columns

I have a table containing pairs for matches, and the table looks like this:

```
|pairing_id|player1_id|player2_id|number_of_round|
| 132      | Thomas   |  Brian   |      1        |
```

I try to write an sql query, which shows me all the redundant pairs, so the pairing is the same if the 2 player names are the same, but for the second time, Brian is player1 and Thomas is the player2.

So this 2 matchups are considered the same pairs, as the player names are the same:

```
|pairing_id|player1_id|player2_id|number_of_round|
| 132      | Thomas   |  Brian   |      1        |
| 458      | Brian    |  Thomas  |      4        |
```

I need to find all the redundant pairings in the table, but sadly I dont know how to query for this.

Comment: And where does the second row in the result set come from?

Comment: I cleared my question (hopefully), basicaly I try to find a way, to find all the duplicated pairs in a table, which is full of randomly generated pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with `EXISTS`

```
select t1.pairing_id, t1.player1_id, t1.player2_id, t1.number_of_round
from myTable t1 
where exists (select null 
              from myTable t2 
              where t2.player1_id = t1.player2_id and t2.player2_id = t1.player1_id)
order by case when t1.player1_id > t1.player2_id then t1.player2_id else t1.player1_id end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `exists`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where pairing_id <> t.pairing_id and player1_id = t.player2_id and player2_id = t.player1_id 
)
```